# Handle POST in express with mongoDB and socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I have a really strange question and I will try to explain it:
I send a POST request to server and I save the body in the DB which functions I have exported in a seperate file. How can I also emit what was saved via socket, since I cannot require('socket.io') in my ./database.js ?

Here's a snippet:

```
var app = require('express')();
var database = require('./database');
var serv = require('http').createServer(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(serv);
....

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    database.save(model, req.body, res); //it saves the body to mongo and it works
    *edit//If I paste the code of database.save() here as is I can invoke emit
    //Here I want to emit the same data too
    //If I use the following I am receiving Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
     socket.emit('value', JSON.stringify(req.body));
};
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do anything with the sockets. Show me your `database.save()` function. I suspect you are doing `res.json()` multiple times there.

Comment: @AnkitGomkale the problem is that I don't know how to pass the emit from an external file. If I paste my code database.save() inside post function I can invoke emit without any problems. That solution unfortunately makes the code really difficult to follow, that's why I keep organizing my chunks in separate files.